# Difference between these 2 selectors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In a web page, there are multiple div elements, some of which have a class of 'class1'.

**Question:** Will both the below selectors give us all div elements having a class of class1?

```
$("div .class1")

$("div.class1")
```

Comment: This has more to do with css than jquery. I am sure someone has asked the same question before I just can't find it

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors for a discussion of selector syntax.

Comment: @Huangism, I tried finding it here and on google, but couldn't get a full answer.

Comment: Tecnically, both will, if all `.class1` elements are descendants of at least one div element. Otherwise, only the second selector.

Comment: @LcSalazar no the first will give any element with `.class1` which does not satisfy the OP's question

Comment: @Huangism, he didn't asked for *only* div elements, but if it would return *all* div elements. As I said, tecnically, it might.

Comment: @LcSalazar perhaps you missed it `Will both the below selectors give us all div elements having a class of class1?`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two selectors do very different things.

This selector:

```
$("div .class1")
```

will return any element (regardless of element type) which has a class of `class1` and is a descendant (immediate or otherwise) of a `div` (regardless of that `div`'s class, if any).

This selector:

```
$("div.class1")
```

will return any `div` which has a class of `class1`.

Comment: By descendants, does it also include the parent div if the parent div has callas of 'class1'?

Comment: @Sunil: A "parent" isn't a descendant, is it?  If you have a `div` which has a descendant `div`, the latter of which has a class of `class1`, then the descendant `div` would be returned by the first selector.  (In fact, it would be returned by both.)

Answer (score 7):

The first one will select an element that has the class `class1` that is a descendant of a `div`.

```
<div>
    <p class="class1">text</p> <-- selected
</div>
```

The second one will select a `div` that has the class `class1`.

```
<div class="class1">  <-- selected
    <p>text</p>
</div>
```

> Will both the below selectors give us all div elements having a class
>   of class1?

No, only the second one, `$("div.class1")`, will. In both jQuery and CSS, a space in front of a class means that you are looking for a descendant element with that class.

Answer (score 1):

The first selector gives you all the `.class1` elements that are descendants of any `<div>` element.

The second will give you all the `.class1` elements that **are** actually `<div>`s themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Nop.

The first one will give you elements in `div` which have class `class1` and the second one will give you the div with class 'class1`.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the to selectors you've posted is the element hierarchy.

Lets say that you have a code like this:

```
<div class="class1">
    This is a div with class name class1
</div>
<div>
    This is a div with no class name</div>
    <span class="class1">This is a span with class name class1</span>
<div class="class1">
    This is a div with class name class1
</div>
<div>
    This is a div with no class name
    <p class="class1">This is a paragraph with class name class1</p>
</div>
<div class="class1">
    This is a div with class name class1
</div>
<div class="class1">
    This is a div with class name class1
    <div class="class1">
        This is a div with class name class1
    </div>
 </div>
```

The selector `$("div .class1")` will return you all the elements inside of `<div>` element which has the class name `class1`. In our example, that would be `<span class="class1">...</span>`, `<p class="class1">...</p>` and the last div `<div class="class1">...</div>`

whereas the selector $("div.class1") will return you all the elements of `<div>` which has the class name `class1`. In our example, that would be all instances of `<div class="class1">`.

here's a fiddle to help you understand more: http://jsfiddle.net/fatgamer85/m99onozo/1/

hope this helps.